# "Зависть" or "ревность"

Tags: разница

I'm trying to understand what is the difference in meaning between these two words: **Зависть** and **ревность**, I used both in meaning of "to be jealous" but I was told by someone that there is a difference between them (since the explanation was in Russian language I'm not sure that I understood it). What is this difference?

Comment: [Чем зависть отличается от ревности?](http://www.psychologies.ru/self-knowledge/behavior/chem-zavist-otlichaetsya-ot-revnosti/)

Answer (score 11):

It's simple:

**зависть** – envy (a feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else's possessions, qualities, or luck)

**ревность** – jealousy (affection-related, as if when a man is jealous of his wife or children of their parents etc.)

Both words are nouns. Note the spelling: it's "завист**ь**", not "завис**т**".

Comment: Jealousy can mean either and that caused the difficulty. А couple of typical examples could help to explain it.

Comment: @Alex_ander *Ревность* involves a third party's affections. Usually sexual, but can apply to siblings with respect to parents, or two friends of the same person.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov It's true for the Russian word, but the two English versions are often used as synonyms:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/jealous-vs-envious

Comment: @Alex_ander I know.That's why I'm explaining it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you work from the English word 'jealous' it is true that both these words can be used, but only in accurate senses. See OALD definitions for 'jealous':

> 1) feeling angry or unhappy because somebody you like or love is
>   showing interest in somebody else  - In Russian this implies
>   **ревность**.
>
> 2) jealous (of somebody/something) - feeling angry or unhappy because you wish you had something that somebody else has  - In
>   Russian it is usually understood as **зависть**.

So in these senses "to be jealous (of)" applies.

As for definitions of the Russian words:

> **Зависть** usually means **envy**. And mostly used in this sense (sometimes in a positive way of course, or as a joke)
>
> **Ревность** has at least 3 senses:
>
> 1) Jealousy in love, feelings, etc.
>
> 2) Being angry when someone is successful and you are not (e.g. at work)
>
> 3) *obsolete* *meaning*, zeal, huge desire, actions or energy to do or achieve something

Comment: I would not call the third meaning of `Ревность` obsolete but rather literary/bookish as it is indeed completely normal to use it these days.

Comment: @user7808407 , I am afraid I haven't provided the name of the source. It's Большой толковый словарь РЯ, Кузнецов 2000. The 3rd sense is described as устар. (which I translated as "obsolete").

Answer (score 0):

To add to what was said above, the grammatical constructions for these two words are different.

завидовать (кому) 
For example, if  someone just got a ticket to a movie you wanted to see you might hear: "Я завидую тебе белой завистью. - This is a "friendly" sort of envy, if such a thing exists. You're happy for the other person but don't secretly covet what they want.

-ревновать кого к кому-

Ревную свою девушку к её бывшему
I'm jealous of my girlfriend over/because of her past boyfriend.